# How to run Azure functions on Visual Studio 2017 correctly?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blockchain-workbench

I am trying to run a program that is using Azure Functions. I am using Visual Studio 2017. This is the program:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/blockchain/tree/master/blockchain-workbench/rest-api-samples/dotnet

I downloaded everything that is related to Azure Functions.

When I press debug I get the following error:

> A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started directly In order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project.

Am I running this example correctly or did I miss something that is related to Azure functions?

Thanks

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, I don't see any Azure Function alike code in the linked project. Did you create a sample trigger and refactor it accordingly? Follow the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs#prerequisites) to validate your steps.

Comment: Oh my bad, I accidentally pasted the wrong URL. Fixed now. There is a HttpTrigger there which baffles me (new to Azure functions). Thanks!

Comment: Could you verify you work with latest Azure function and Web Jobs Tools? check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs#check-your-tools-version), see 15.10.2046 now. Also could you delete the package `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` and add it using nuget again?

Comment: Ok, I am using the most updated tools. deleteing the package and adding it again did help. Now I get a weird error where I press F5 and it prompts the CLI and it simply says "Unable to find function project root. Expecting to have host.json in function project root." As you can see in the github of the project, there is a folder called "functionSource" that has a host.json file there. Do I need to define this folder as the root? if so, how? Thanks for your help

Comment: You are right, the `functionSource` folder is function project folder, other content seems not useful for Azure Function. In VS, open new project, select `Functions.csproj` should work.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Now everything seems to works fine with Azure functions. I now get some problems that is related to the blockchain workbench but this deserves a thread of its own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions`(used to build Function project) seems broken, try to delete the reference and re-install package using nuget.

As for the error

> Unable to find function project root. Expecting to have host.json in function project root

In VS, open new project and select `Functions.csproj` to locate the project.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Try to degrade Microsoft.Net.SDK.Functions, I degraded it from 1.0.29 to 1.0.28 and it started working.

There seems to be some problem with the Nuget Package.